# Solve an equation in real numbers if the parameters are also real.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Solve an equation in real numbers if $a$ and $b$ are also real $$\left| a^2-2 a-b^2-4 b-x \right| +
> \left| a^2-2 a-b^2-4 b-3 x+2\right| +\\
> \left| a^2-2 a+b^2+4 b+2 x \right| +
> a^2-2 a+b^2+4 b+18 \left| x-2 \right| +11 x=20 $$

**Here is a long solution. Any shorter and more elegant?**

Let $c= a^2-2a+1$ and $d=b^2+4b+4$.

Now we have a following situation:

$$\left| c-1-d+4-x \right| +
\left| c-1-d+4-3 x+2\right| +\\
\left| c-1+d-4+2 x \right| +
c-1+d-4+18 \left| x-2 \right| +11 x=20 $$

Now let $m=c+d-5$ and $n=c-d+3$ then:

$$\left| n-x \right| +
\left| n-3 x+2\right| +\\
\left|m+2 x \right| +
m+5+18 \left| x-2 \right| +11 x=25 $$

By triangle inequality we have:

$$\left|x-n \right| +
\left| n-3 x+2\right| \geq |2-2x|$$

Since $m+5\geq 0$ we have $m+5=|m+5|$ so:
$$\left|-m-2 x \right| +
|m+5|\geq |-2x+5|$$

So for all $x$ which solves this equation they must satisfy also this inequality:$$ 25 \geq |2-2x|+|-2x+5|+18|x-2|+11x $$

Since the function $f(x)=|2-2x|+|-2x+5|+18|x-2|+11x$ has minimum $25$ at $x=2$  this equation has at most one solution at $x=2$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

We have $$\left| p-x \right| +
\left|p-3 x+2\right| +
\left| q+2 x \right| +
q+18 \left| x-2 \right| +11 x-20, $$

a piecewise linear function. $p$ is free and $q\ge-5$.

Such functions have roots when the values at two successive endpoints have opposite signs. In this case, the "corner points" are

$$x=p,\frac{p+2}3,-\frac q2,2$$ and the corresponding values

$$\left|-2p+2\right| +
\left| q+2 p\right| +
q+18 \left| p-2 \right| +11p-20, $$

$$\left|\frac{2p-2}3\right| +
\left| q+2\frac{p+2}3 \right| +
q+18 \left| \frac{p+2}3-2 \right| +11 \frac{p+2}3-20, $$

$$\left| p+\frac q2 \right| +
\left|p+3 \frac q2+2\right| +
q+18 \left| -\frac q2-2 \right| -11\frac q2-20, $$

$$\left| p-2 \right| +
\left|p-4\right| +
\left| q+4\right| +
q+2.$$

Now you have to discuss the signs of these expressions and order the corner points.